# render single quotes in element attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following cshtml

```
<option value='@rtcrs.val' @(res.val == rtcrs.val? "selected = 'selected'" : "" )>@rtcrs.valName</option>
```

Which is rendering

```
<option value='1' selected = &#39;selected&#39;>Started</option>
```

Obviously, I'd like to preserve the actual single quotes. What am I missing here?

Comment: [This post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) indicates that using `@Html.Raw(...)` should produce unencoded output, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: why not using the DropDownListFor helper ?